# Why can't I make a Google account profile photo my SO profile pic but in other sites I can?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, profile-picture

I have seen a few people have different different profile avatars on different different part of Stack Exchange, like a different profile pic in Stack Overflow and on Arqade, so I also decided to change, but I have an issue.

If I try to edit my profile image on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), it gives an option to make my Google profile picture as the profile image. But if I try to edit my Stack Overflow profile image it doesn't give me that option. Is it bug or is there a reason behind that?

I can do the same in few other Stack Exchange sites, but in others I can't.

**Stack Overflow profile avatar** option:

[image: SO image option]

**Arqade profile avatar** option:

[image: Arqade]

Comment: Oddly I get the same list on all sites which is Uploaded picture, Identicon and Gravatar. I don't see Google anywhere at all. I joined Arcade and it's the same. Oh, and I log in to SO only with Google.

Comment: @DavidG not sure about your case but i have logged in via gmail account and in some SE sites i can see gmail profile pic and in some i cant.

Comment: Yeah, I was just pointing out that mine was different to yours too.

Comment: Yup..create a question too :p

Comment: @superphonic uh, I don't know.